# Separating nodes in this Tikz diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]


\begin{figure}[ht] % 'ht' tells LaTeX to place the figure 'here' or at the top of the page
\centering % centers the figure
\scalebox{1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block] (data) {Data/Reality};

\node[block, right of=data] (physical) {Physical Model};

\node[block, right of=physical] (emulator) {Computer Models (emulators, etc.)};

\node[cloud, below of=data] (SU) {Structural Uncertainty};

\node[cloud, below of=physical] (AU) {Algorithmic Uncertainty};


\draw
(SU) edge[above] node{} (physical)
;

\draw[dashed]
(emulator) edge[above] node{} (AU);


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Diagram of Computer Modelling}
\label{Computer Modelling}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The problem with this code is that the nodes imposed on each other... is there a way to solve this automatically, instead of just using xshift on each nodes?

Comment: As always on this site please make your example into a self contained document others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif my mistake... I copied from the wrong tex file. I hope it now works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With correct using of `node distance` nodes' shapes should not to overlap. Also with small redefinition of your nodes' styles you can easy fit your image in a text area without scaling of image (scaling should be avoided!).

Considering aforementioned, the MWE with your image can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes}               

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht] 
\centering 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 4mm,       % <---
 block/.style =  {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, 
                  text width=#1, align=center, minimum height=4em}, % <---
 block/.default = 6em,                                              % <---
 cloud/.style = {ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, 
                 text width=7em, align=center, inner xsep=0pt},     % <---
                        ]
\node (data)        [block]                 {Data/ Reality};
\node (physical)    [block,right=of data]   {Physical Model};
\node (emulator)    [block=8em,                                     % <---
                     right=of physical]     {Computer Models\\ (emulators, etc.)};
\node (SU)          [cloud,below=of data]   {Structural\\ Uncertainty};
\node (AU)          [cloud,right=of SU]     {Algorithmic\\ Uncertainty};
%
\draw           (SU) -- (physical);
\draw[dashed]   (emulator) -- (AU);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagram of Computer Modelling}
\label{Computer Modelling}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

- changes in code in comparison to your MWE are indicated by `% <---`
  (red lines indicate text borders)
- use of `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Instead it use `tikzset` or write styles as options of `tikzpicture` (as is done in above MWE)
- use of `\scalebox{1}{...}` is desperate action of the last resort.Always try to design image such, that it can fit without scaling in text (or some environment). For example, break long text in nodes into more lines (as I do in `cloud` nodes, for this I change its style)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zarko. By the way, when I use \\ on the nodes, I get a compilation error... Have you altered the code in a specific way to correct this?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it from the cloud definition. Thanks ;) +1

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, in code are all changes in comparison to your code indicated by `% <---`.

Answer (score 1):

I would position the nodes individually. But one automatic fix is to specify a node distance just after beginning the picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6cm]
```

Or whatever distance you want.

Comment: Colin, thanks for your answer

Comment: +1 I forgot to say this ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simpler is to use the `positioning library` and `right=of...` instead of `right of=...`. The positioning library takes care of node size when it positions nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, anchor=west]

\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]


\begin{figure}[ht] % 'ht' tells LaTeX to place the figure 'here' or at the top of the page
\centering % centers the figure
\scalebox{1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block] (data) {Data/Reality};

\node[block,right=of data] (physical) {Physical Model};
\node[block,right=of physical] (emulator) {Computer Models (emulators, etc.)};
\node[cloud,below=of data] (SU) {Structural Uncertainty};
\node[cloud,right=of SU] (AU) {Algorithmic Uncertainty};


\draw (SU) edge[above] node{} (physical);

\draw[dashed](emulator) edge[above] node{} (AU);


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Diagram of Computer Modelling}
\label{Computer Modelling}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Note that I had to set the position the last node (AU) relatively to its left node to avoid overlapping as the positioning library only takes of the node given as an argument.

As usual, node relative spacing can be set with `node distance`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 ;)